# Apple app store same app is on sale with different names for different countries?

Tags: ios, app-store

In app store I see that some application names are different in some app stores. The applications were all the same but their names change according to the country store. How can it be done? Do I need to send my app for each store with diffrent name or is there an option for that?

Can I add this feature to my app with a patch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide - Localizing Metadata, Keywords, and Screenshots](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/8_AddingNewApps/AddingNewApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH13-SW15)

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/8_AddingNewApps/AddingNewApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH13-SW15

Comment: it says that I can only add language if my app was on editable stage but mine is submited so what can I add it with a patch ?

Comment: You can only do this when you submit a new app or a new binary (update) to an existing app.